# How do I make a simple form GET and POST using Express and Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to follow this [Express.js and MongoDB tutorial](http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/03/a-sample-app-with-node-js-express-and-mongodb-part-1/) with the difference of making my index page have a form where you save an email address.

This is the main code so far:

**emailprovider.js**

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Connection = require('mongodb').Connection;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var BSON = require('mongodb').BSON;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

EmailProvider = function(host, port) {
  this.db= new Db('email-test', new Server(host, port, {safe: false}, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
  this.db.open(function(){});
};


EmailProvider.prototype.getCollection= function(callback) {
  this.db.collection('emails', function(error, email_collection) {
    if( error ) callback(error);
    else callback(null, email_collection);
  });
};

//save new email
EmailProvider.prototype.save = function(emails, callback) {
    this.getCollection(function(error, email_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        if( typeof(emails.address)=="undefined")
          emails = [emails];

        for( var i =0;i< emails.address;i++ ) {
          email = emails[i];
          email.created_at = new Date();
        }

        email_collection.insert(emails, function() {
          callback(null, emails);
        });
      }
    });
};

exports.EmailProvider = EmailProvider;
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , EmailProvider = require('./emailprovider').EmailProvider;

var app = express();

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);


//Routes


//get new email form
app.get('/email/new', function(req, res) {
    res.render('email_new', {
        title: 'Email Address'
    });
});


//save new email
app.post('/email/new', function(req, res){
    emailProvider.save({
        address: req.param('name')
    }, function( error, docs) {
        res.redirect('/')
    });
});
```

**index.js**

```
  .form-area
    form(method='post')
     input(type='text', name='address', placeholder='Your email address')
     input(type='submit', value='Send')
```

I really don't have a clue what's going on in the emailprovider. I kinda got the routes down but right now when I try to save a new Email I get a `Cannot POST /` 404 error message. What's the correct way to do this?

Thanks.

EDIT: removed extra commas in jade syntax for input attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EmailProvider variable is a reference to function and not an object instance. This may cause two problems:

1. The ***`this`*** operator on EmailProvider.js might not refer to EmailProvider as you wish.
2. Every call to `EmailProvider.save()` will run the `db.collection` again which can cause performance issues, memory leak as well other issues.

You should create an object instance from EmailProvider as follow:

```
var app = express();
var emailProvider = new EmailProvider(<some host>, <some port>);
...
```

If ***`this`*** operator causes problem (such as it does not recognize EmailProvider methods) call the `call` function after the `save` function as follow:

```
//save new email
app.post('/email/new', function(req, res){
  emailProvider.save({
      address: req.param('name')
  }, function( error, docs) {
      res.redirect('/')
  }).call(emailProvider);
});
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks I missed that. I put my host and port, just like in the tutorial as `var emailProvider= new EmailProvider('localhost', 27017);` and my `req.param` to `('address')` instead of `'name'`.